# One word for playing on the violin with a bow

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

When one is playing on the guitar, one is *strumming*. One can strum on the strings of a violin too. But most of the time, one *uses a bow to play on the violin*. Is there a single word for that?

Comment: FWIW, violinist very seldom talk about _strumming_. The general term for anything you do with the hands only is _pizzicato_. (In German this is also sometimes used informally as a verb, _pizzen_ – not sure whether something similar is said in English. _To pizz_?)

Comment: @leftaroundabout - The written abbreviation on the score is usually *pizz*. However I don't think anyone says it. It would sound somewhat like "piss" in English.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK "pizzicato" is an Italian word and it's pronounced "pitz" in English, at least by all the string-players I know (except for the ones who eat pissa not pizza.)

Comment: Actually there are a few "classical" pieces where the violin section is requested to hold their instruments like guitars (or mandolins, which are tuned the same as the violin) and "strum". The first occurrence I know of was in one of Monteverdi's operas, around 1600.

Comment: *Strumming* is just one of several techniques one can use for the more general activity of *playing the guitar*.

Comment: Fiddling as with *fiddler on the roof*? Why not?

Comment: @leftaroundabout The verb used by violinists is often *pluck*. *Pizzicato* describes a section of music which is played by plucking.

Comment: @BlessedGeek Some violinists would be insulted to be said to be _fiddling_, as _fiddle_ or _fiddler_ are terms typically associated with self-taught violin players that play folk music.

Comment: If you're gonna play in texas, 
You gotta have a fiddle in the band.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**bowing**

How to Use Exquisite Bowing Techniques on a Violin. 
http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Exquisite-Bowing-Techniques-on-a-Violin

Comment: I know it sounds like it's too good to be true, but this is a very common and very accurate verb for the action.

Comment: Pronounced "Boeing".

Comment: @GEdgar But, if your bowing is good enough, you get to do some bowing afterwards.

Comment: And if the bow gets hung up somehow you get a "boing".

Answer (score 20):

There are several specific adjectives phrases to describe the exact manner of bowing, but the general word is ***arco***.
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/arco#English

Here is a good introductory glossary of specific techniques:
http://beststudentviolins.com/terms.pdf

<digression>

*Arco* is the Italian word for bow, so the word for bowing is essentially "bowing", and when speaking in English--especially in informal situations--it would be acceptable to simply use the word *bowing*.  Like many musical terms however, the traditional Italian version is preferred by those-in-the-know.

</digression>

<unwarranted pedantry>

While one may say generally that a guitar is played by strumming, *strumming* is only a category of articulation (like *arco* is a category of articulation).  Specifically, strumming is a continuous stroke by finger or pick across several strings; if only one string is articulated we categorise that a *pluck* instead.  Plucking can be further described: up strokes and down strokes, free strokes or rest strokes, finger strokes or picked strokes, etc...
In other words it is inaccurate (or at least neither specific nor rigorous) to say that guitar is played only by strumming.  A variety of articulations exist on guitar and strumming is a class of articulation.

Likewise there are a variety of arco articulations: up stroke and down stroke, sul tasto or sul pontecillo, detache or legato, etc...

On viols (the violin's family) strumming is technically possible, but incredibly rare.  Plucking (one string) is what you are thinking of.  In orchestras this is usually called *[pizzicato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pizzicato)* (abbreviated *pizz*) because that is the Italian word for "plucked".

In practice *arco* is often used as a sort of antonym to *pizz*.  So a violinist might see a part of her music marked *pizz* where she should pluck and a part marked *arco* where she should use her bow again.

</unwarranted pedantry>

As reward for reading this rambling wall of text, here's a pretty sweet cover of Jimmy Page's solo from *Dazed and Confused*, which is played with a bow (arco) on a guitar: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7R6yUyUPd7o

Comment: Good, but the [viol family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viol) and the [violin family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violin_family) are different things. The violin is from the violin family not from the viol family.

Comment: "Bowing" is much, much more common in everyday usage, and will be almost universally understood, but this answer treats is as a side note. You even use it in defining the term "arco", which isn't used at all outside the classical world, and within it shares space with "bowing". This answer doesn't give "bowing" enough credit.

Comment: 1) I think by definition those of us on ELU are pedants, so it's always warranted :) 2) Jimmy Page is/was amazing, and has some ridiculously long fingers.

Comment: @karen musical notation is always in italian.  So while bowing is the layman's term, arco is the musician's term.

Comment: As a violinist who was once taught by a former lead violinist of a large city's symphony orchestra, I've always referred to it as "bowing" in speech, as did my aforementioned teacher. *Arco* is seen on sheet music where *pizz* is also featured (if it's not mentioned, *arco* is the default) but when actually speaking we always said that a section should be "bowed", rather than "played *arco*". The only person I've ever known to call it "playing *arco*" was a conductor I once had... who was a clarinetist. Take that as you will.

Answer (score 6):

I think you are referring to [*fiddling*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fiddle). The "normal" way of playing a violin is to *fiddle* it.

> fid·dle  (fĭd′l) n.
>   1. A violin, especially one used to play folk or country music.
>
> v.intr.
>   1. To play a fiddle.
>
> v.tr.
>   1. To play (a tune) on a fiddle.

To stress the fact that one is using the bow (e.g. as opposed to strumming or *plucking* the strings in a [pizzicato](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/10255/what-do-you-call-plucking-the-violin-strings-with-the-finger-rather-than-using)), then you would use the term *bowing*.

But for the subtler meanings I'd ask http://music.stackexchange.com .

Comment: No... you fiddle a fiddle. They may be the same instrument but the method of playing them is vastly different.

Comment: The term seems indeed to have evolved, but fiddling *is* playing a violin using a bow. It may have differences in style - i.e. in *how* you move the bow. See http://www.vithefiddler.com/difference-between-fiddle-and-violin/

Comment: Your very statement says "the normal way" is to fiddle it... but the dictionary definition clearly shows that it only relates to folk or country music applications.

Comment: It says that it *especially* relates to -- not that it *only* relates to. I admit this might be perceived as a *fiddling* distinction.

Comment: Isemi is correct: refer this to the music site.

Answer (score 4):

Just for completeness' sake (there are already better answers): *Playing*.

Generally speaking, if you are writing a story or something and say someone was playing the violin, the assumption is that a bow is involved. It will provide the right mental image, and as the most familiar and common term, is probably what you want in almost all cases.

But, because you are asking this question, and used the word "playing" in the question, I'm assuming this is not one of those common cases.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some sentences to give you a feel for these words and how they're used:

The violin is a bowed instrument.

This piece is entirely plucked.  The violinists will set their bows in their laps.

The next piece is mostly bowed, but there are a few small plucked sections.

The bowing here is a little tricky but I've marked all your parts.  [There are symbols that let the musicians know what direction the bow should move for each note.]